# Why does my minimap viewport rectangle pan while zooming?

Tags: d3.js, zooming, viewport, pan

I created a CodePen to illustrate my problem:

See the CodePen [Simple Minimap dashed Viewport](https://codepen.io/StephanT/pen/GZzPaX/).

I'm part of a small team, my job is (among others) to do the minimap.
The code in the pen is a boiled-down version of our code regarding the minimap.
I'm new to d3js, so I'm happy to hear anything which could be improved about it.

I'm stuck with the bug regarding the dashed rectangle, which is supposed to show what part of the big map we can see.
Panning works, zooming might be finished - the (in my eyes) only technical problem remaining is that the dashed rectangle also pans when you zoom.
The zoom-panning amount is dependant on the mouse position - if the mouse is in the top-left corner, panning is minimal. The further the mouse moves to bottom or right (or both), the more this bug becomes apparent.

I'm using d3.event to get information about pan & zoom amount, and noticed that even if you do not pan at all, if you only zoom, d3.event.translate[0/1] contains values != zero.
Is my approach wrong? Being a new member of the team, I cannot change much of the code, but I can change everything regarding the minimap.

I need to capture pan and zoom events from

```
    var rect = svg.append("rect")
        ...   
        .style("pointer-events", "all");
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm stuck on that problem for days now, any help would be appreciated a lot. Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<div class="canvas" id="canvas"></div>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

.canvas
{
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  left: 7%;
  top: 10%;
}

.minimap {  
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid #c2d1f0;
    bottom: 2%;
    right: 2%;
}
```

JS:

```
var width = 800;
var height = 500;

var canvas = d3.select("#canvas")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([0.1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = canvas.append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .call(zoom);

// invisible rectangle to handle mouse interaction
var rect = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("pointer-events", "all");

var group = svg.append("g");


function zoomed() {
  group.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");

  // update the minimap whenever pan or zoom have happened
  updateMinimap();
}

// an array of circles just to have something to look at and as orientation
var circles = [
  {x: 150, y: 100}, 
  {x: 50, y: 50}, 
  {x: 80, y: 350},
  {x: 200, y: 150},
  {x: 350, y: 200},
  {x: 140, y: 300},
  {x: 230, y: 280}
];

// draw those circles
group.selectAll("circle")
  .data(circles)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("fill", "red")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x;})  
  .attr("cy", function(d) {return d.y;})

var minimapScale = 1 / 3;   // size of big map times this = size of minimap
var minimapWidth = width * minimapScale;
var minimapHeight = height * minimapScale;

var minimap = canvas.append("svg")
  .attr("class", "minimap")
  .attr("width", minimapWidth)
  .attr("height", minimapHeight);

// run it once so we can see it even if no action was done
updateMinimap();

function updateMinimap() {
  // clear outdated objects from minimap
  minimap.selectAll("*").remove();

  // set default values
  var scale = 1;
  var dx = 0;
  var dy = 0;

  if (d3.event) { // overwrite those values when necessary
    scale = d3.event.scale;
    dx = -d3.event.translate[0] * minimapScale;
    dy = -d3.event.translate[1] * minimapScale;
  }

  // debug output
  //console.log("scale: " + scale + ", dx: " + dx + ", dy: " + dy);

  // repaint objects on minimap
  group.selectAll("*").each(function (circle) {
    var cx = circle.x * minimapScale;
    var cy = circle.y * minimapScale;
    minimap.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 2)
      .attr("fill", "blue")
      .attr("cx", cx)
      .attr("cy", cy);
  });

  // draw the dashed rectangle, indicating where we are on the big map
  drawDashedRectangle(scale, dx, dy);
}

function drawDashedRectangle(scale, dx, dy) {
  minimap.append("rect")
    .attr("x", dx)
    .attr("y", dy)
    .attr("width", minimapWidth / scale)
    .attr("height", minimapHeight / scale)
    .style("stroke-dasharray", (10, 5))
    .style("stroke-width", 2)
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .style("fill", "none");
}
```

We'd like to have [something like that](http://www.billdwhite.com/wordpress/2013/11/26/d3-minimap-pan-and-zoom-demo/), though we don't need pan/zoom interaction on the minimap. We only need it on the big map, and the minimap should only reflect those changes.

Comment: did you manage to solve this?